# toggle class on click Javascript

Tags: javascript, toggle

I want to know WHY its not working.
I have a bunch of classes called yellow.
I then add an event listener to them with a callback function to activate upon clicking.  What am I not seeing here? :(

```
 function test(){
      var allYellow = document.querySelector('.yellow');
     allYellow.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.classList.toggle = 'testyellow'; 
   })
   }
test();
```

Comment: `this.classList.toggle('testyellow');` `I want to know WHY its not working.`   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: Hi, I read through it and found a new way to code but I still dont understand a- im still relatively new so when I hear terms like "read only property" im not sure what that means in the JS world

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript..

```
function myFunction() {
    var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
}
```

Comment: For your info, i didn't downvoted your previous deleted answer. Now you get my upvote!